# AlpineJS Multiple Class Bindings, x-data, $persist + Flatpickr

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, persist, flatpickr

I am attempting to disable a button using AlpineJS unless certain conditions are met. This is my button code:

```
<button
    class="bg-red p-4 rounded"
    :class="{'opacity-50 pointer-events-none': ((adults + children) === 0), 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none': charter === '' }"
>
Submit
</button>
```

This is my `x-data`, retrieving values from session storage with `$persist`

```
    x-data="{
        destination: $persist('').using(sessionStorage).as('_x_destination'),
        charter: $persist('').using(sessionStorage).as('_x_charterlength'),
        dateRange: $persist([]).using(sessionStorage).as('_x_range'),
        adults: $persist(0).using(sessionStorage).as('_x_adults'),
        children: $persist(0).using(sessionStorage).as('_x_children')
    }"
```

I have 3 different conditions I want to be met in order for the button to have pointe-events. The two above are partially working.

If `adults + children` is equal to `zero`, the button remains with no pointer events. If `adults + children` is equal to one or more, then the button still has no pointer events. This is good so far.

If I then update `charter` to not be `null`, the button now has pointer events and can be clicked.

However, if I the update `charter` to not be `null` first, prior to setting `adults + children` to be greater than zero, then the button somehow becomes active with pointer events before it should.

Not sure why the two conditions above aren't working in conjunction with each other in either scenario.

Additionally, I have a third condition I would like to introduce into the button. That is `x-data` - `dateRange` which is for use with Flatpickr

My Flatpickr code looks like this:

```
    <div x-data="{
        thePicker: null,
        init() {
            this.thePicker = flatpickr(this.$refs.picker, {
                mode: 'range',
                inline: false,
                dateFormat: 'M j',
                showMonths: 2,
                defaultDate: this.dateRange,
                onChange: (selectedDates) => {this.dateRange = [...selectedDates];}
            });
        },
    }"
    >
        <div
        class="flex items-center justify-center w-full overflow-hidden text-sm text-black bg-white border border-gray-400 rounded-lg"
        >
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="ml-4 bi bi-calendar-event-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M4 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V1H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v1h16V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1V.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V1H4zM16 14V5H0v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2m-3.5-7h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5"/>
            </svg>
            <input type="text"
                x-ref="picker"
                placeholder="Add dates"
                class="px-4 py-2 text-sm placeholder-gray-600 border-0 bg-none focus:ring-0 "
            >
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am struggling to determine how to set the 3rd condition, even as the only condition, by setting `'opacity-50 pointer-events-none': dateRange === ''` OR `'opacity-50 pointer-events-none': dateRange === null }`

Nothing I've tried appears to recognize the Flatpickr as not being set.

Comment: I was able to solve my first issue regarding multiple bindings by using ternary conditions within brackets []:

`:class="[((adults + children) === 0) ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none' : '', charter === '' ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none' : '']"`

But I am still struggling with attempting to add a 3rd condition for `dateRange`:

`:class="[((adults + children) === 0) ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none' : '', charter === '' ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none' : '', dateRange === '' ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none' : '']"`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve my own question with:

```
:class="[((adults + children) === 0) ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none' : '', charter === '' ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none' : '', dateRange == '' ? 'opacity-50 pointer-events-none' : '']"
```

Two `==` appear to be the fix.

I am not sure why exactly because it's difficult to find the documentation explaining it but if someone would like to comment why or provide documentation, that would be great.